# How to replace last instance of a string in multiple files in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I need to replace the LAST instance of this:

```
<segment-type>show</segment-type></segment>
```

with this:

```
<segment-type>show</segment-type></segment></play-list>
```

in multiple files.  It has to be the last instance, because that specific string shows up multiple times in each document, but I'm basically try to close an XML file after the last instance because I accidentally deleted the close tag in all the files...and can't undo...

I'm at work, and this is work related, it would be insanely helpful if someone could help me figure this out!  I need some sort of Regex replacement expression but I don't know Regex very well...

Comment: `(?s)<segment-type>show</segment-type></segment>(?!</play-list>)((?:(?!<segment-type>show</segment-type></segment>).)*)\z` --> `<segment-type>show</segment-type></segment></play-list>$1` (no idea why `&‌​#47;` is shown, there must be `/`)

Comment: You just saved my ass, you're an angel <3

Comment: I posted it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

*Find what*: `(?s)<segment-type>show</segment-type></segment>(?!</play-list>)((?:(?!<segment-type>show</segment-type></segment>).)*)\z`
*Replace with*: `<segment-type>show</segment-type></segment></play-list>$1`

The pattern matches:

- `(?s)` - turns on DOTALL mode so that `.` could match newline symbols
- `<segment-type>show</segment-type></segment>(?!</play-list>)` - a `<segment-type>show</segment-type></segment>` substring not followed with `</play-list>` string
- `((?:(?!<segment-type>show</segment-type></segment>).)*)` - Group 1 referenced to with `$1` from the replacement subpattern, matching any char that is not the start of `<segment-type>show</segment-type></segment>` sequence, 0 or more occurrences
- `\z` - end of file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there are ways you could do it with a regex, but a simpler answer might be this:

`1. Click somewhere in the first line of the file`

`2. Press ctrl + f`

`3. Type your </select> end tag in the 'Find What' box`

[image: Type Tag]

`4. Make sure 'Wrap around' is selected`

[image: Wrap Around]

`5. Select the 'Up' option under the 'Direction' options`

[image: Up Direction]

`6. Click on 'Find Next'`

[image: Find Next]

That will then go to the last reference to the `</select>` tag in the current file. Then you can add what you need to.

Comment: Looks like Wiktor Stribiżew beat me with an easier solution while I was typing my answer. Good job Wiktor Stribiżew.

Comment: Well, my solution is not easy, it is easy for the consumer that just has to copy/paste the patterns into 2 text fields, but it is not that easy to understand.

Comment: There actually ended up being some weird issue where the "y" in the replaced "play" was not actually a "y" character, it was charcode 8000 something...I had to do a few more find/replaces to finally fix it so our parser could read the XML, it kept telling me the end tag didn't match the start tag :P This has inspired me to really learn the crap out of Regex sometime soon so I can do this myself!